# UIButton takes 2 seconds to recognize touch

Tags: ios5, uibutton

Very curious -- a standard rounded-rec UIButton in an XIB.  Has touchUpInside linked to a method in the view controller.  On the simulator it works as expected, but on an iOS 5 iPad one must hold the button down for 2 seconds before the linked method (cancelButtonPressed:) is invoked.

Extracting and logging the target actions for the button shows that it is indeed looking for the touchUpInside event for the correct target object and method.

An added (in viewDidAppear) action for a new target method produces the same behavior -- the new method is invoked only when the button is pressed for 2 seconds (and then released).  It gets invoked immediately after the original method.

The caveats:  This setup is, of course, a hair screwy.  This is in a modal view floating over the main screen.  To get here a view was inserted between the VC and its original view, after the VC's view was loaded.

But of course it works great on the simulator.  (And probably on iOS6 hardware too, though I haven't tried.)

So any idea what could create the need to hold the button down for 2 seconds?  The button "animates" (turns color) instantly on being touched, so it's not simply taking the touch a long time to propagate.

**More info:** Order of operations

- Create a relatively normal view controller
- Create a new UIView, make view controller's view this new view, add VC's original view as a subview to this new view
- Add touch gesture recognizers to the two views, so that a touch outside the VC's original view can be recognized.  (One is added to the VC's original view so that touches there can be ignored.)
- Create a UIWindow, set to "normal window"
- Set new window's root view controller to be the above view controller
- `makeKeyAndVisible` on the new window.

(This (almost) successfully creates a "popup window" with the selected VC.)

**Observations:**

- The button responds instantly to the touch (by changing color), so there's no delay in the touch info filtering through to the view.
- The button touch is only effective, though, after HOLDING the button down for about 2 seconds, so it's not simply that the touch event is being delayed getting delivered.
- Thus, something must be affecting the button-specific logic that decides if a touch has occurred.

**Aha!**

While writing this it occurred to me that the gesture recognizers might somehow be involved.  Disabled them and there's no longer the problem.  These are UITapGestureRecognizers, and shouldn't (one would think) affect the button response (since this same scheme is advocated elsewhere for detecting touches "outside" of a box).  (The gesture recognizer handlers are invoked immediately.)

(Not that this knowledge does me much good, other than maybe I could get away with disabling the "touch outside the box" feature on iOS 5.)

Comment: Are you adding the viewcontroller as a childViewController?

Comment: The view controller is the rootViewController of a UIWindow.

Comment: Hrm...I'd really need to see how you are setting up your view controllers. You're initing it from the app delegate? It could be nothing, but I'm guessing it's something to do with your view/controller hierarchy.

Comment: This is a modal view, overlaying the "main" view.  The window and everything else gets created on the fly, when the modal view is presented.  (I don't have the code at hand right now, or I'd give more of a play-by-play.)

Answer (score 2):

Do this to avoid it in iOS5:

```c
- (void)tappedAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender  {
    float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (version < 6.0) {
        CGPoint pt = [sender locationInView:_button];
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(pt));
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( _button.bounds, pt)) {
            [self buttonAction:_button];
            return;
        }
    }          
    // do some Tapped Action
    NSLog(@"tappedAction:");
}
```